# Issue with uploading multi part image file with dio in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload, multipartform-data, dio

I used **Dio** framework to upload image to server in my flutter app. Dio version 3.0.9.
Post method.
Added 4 headers
Created form data with image and other fields.

I have analysed many more methods. Like degrading Dio to **2.3.1**, to use **UploadFileInfo** method. Not a success. Then with **multipartfileupload**. Finally this one.

```
Future<bool> createStoreWithDio() async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "authorization": tokenString,
      "authtype": "admin",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    };
    try {
      FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
        "logo": await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("logo", imageFile.path,
            contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png')),
        "name": " Bala ios",
        "description": "_description",
        "website": "www.website.com",
        "password": "Test password",
        "user_name": "Test userInformationName",
        "mobile": "9988776655",
        "email": "test@techit.io",
   
      });

      print(formData.fields);
      Response response = await dio
          .post(
        "API",
        data: formData,
        options: Options(
          headers: headers,
        ),
      )
          .then((value) {
        print(value.toString());
      });
      print(response.toString());
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

**imageFile** is the file I captured from camera/ gallery.

I am getting **500** exception. Any help would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what caused this,this code is used in an app i have change based on your code,but i am not sending any headers so you need to add then try with this code let me know it it's work for you.also make sure you have file `imageFile.path` also your api url is correct or not
make sure you have imported

```
`'import  package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
  import 'package:mime/mime.dart';`

 Dio dio = new Dio();
      final mimeTypeData =
      lookupMimeType(imageFile.path, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]).split('/');
      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "name": " Bala ios",
        "description": "_description",
        "website": "www.website.com",
        "password": "Test password",
        "user_name": "Test userInformationName",
        "mobile": "9988776655",
        "email": "test@techit.io",
        "logo": await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile.path,
            contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1])),
      });

      var response = await dio.post(
        Urls.ImageInsert,
        data: formData,
      );

      var message = response.data['message'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I still get the 500 exception

Comment: Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [500]

Comment: The server didn't like something and returned status code 500, which typically means "server error",may be something wrong with header values ,did you try to upload a data with postman with this API,@chandru

Comment: can you upload data without sending any header you have to change the API for test@chandru

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221550/discussion-between-chandru-and-morbius-black).